# px4flow velocity calcuation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a px4flow smart camera sensor, and use the [px4flow_node](http://wiki.ros.org/px4flow_node) to read the sensor output.

The topic /px4flow/optflow has a message type:

```
Header header

float32 ground_distance  # distance to ground in meters
int16   flow_x           # x-component of optical flow in pixels
int16   flow_y           # y-component of optical flow in pixels
float32 velocity_x       # x-component of scaled optical flow in m/s
float32 velocity_y       # y-component of scaled optical flow in m/s
uint8   quality          # quality of optical flow estimate
```

But when I see the output I only have values for flow_x and flow_y.
I am only using it for a 2D robot so assuming I always know the ground distance, can someone please tell me how to calculate the x and y velocities using the flow_x and flow_y values?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267504/px4flow-velocity-calcuation/) by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2017-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

real point P (X,Y,Z), image plane projection p (x,y,z), focal-length f, distance-to-scene Z
X = x*Z / f
Y = y*Z / f

Divide X and Y by the flow integration time(time between frames for which optical flow was calculated) to get velocity. Based on: https://github.com/PX4/Flow/blob/6c8cdb3cc04a5854a7b50e76e267e35507a0a0c4/src/modules/flow/main.c#L434-L438

---

Originally posted by [ashwinvk94](https://answers.ros.org/users/32850/ashwinvk94/) with karma: 16 on 2020-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-10**:
Please use *permalinks* in the future.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-11**:
What I added to your answer was already a permalink and took you directly to the file and lines in question. Why did you change it?